# Pathogen bundles not being saved by git

Tags: git, vim, git-submodules, pathogen

**Original question**
Pathogen bundles not being loaded.
I'm running Kali Linux and I've set up my .vimrc in the recommended way

```
set nocompatible

execute pathogen#infect('~/.vim/bundle/{}')

filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on

syntax enable
colorscheme solarized
```

but this gives me errors for any of the bundles I have installed (e.g. `E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree` or `E185: Cannot find colorscheme 'solarized'`)

Running the following commands once vim has launched, shows that the directory is correct.

`echo pathogen#glob_directories("~/.vim/bundle/*")`
---> all of my bundles are returned

Is there anything else I'm missing?

**Update**
I have all of my dotfiles in a git repo. But when I run a `git add`, only the directories of the bundles are added but none of the files themselves. How do I include pathogen bundles in my "dotfiles" repo?

Comment: Why not simply `execute pathogen#infect()`?

Comment: @romainl I tried that initially but added in the path to confirm I was looking at the same place with `pathogen#glob_directories("~/.vim/bundle/*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a git issue. Because I have my dotfiles in a git repo, when I installed the bundles I should have used:

```
git submodule init
git submodule add https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
git submodule add --depth=1 https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic.git ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic
...
```

As opposed to

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
...
```

After running a `pull` on a different machine. I needed to install these submodules

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

**note**

I had to tinker with the file  `~/.gitmodules` to get my paths set to something that could be used under different usernames and systems